# How to edit a .gpg file with vi?

Tags: encryption, openbsd, vi, gpg

So I created a gpg encrypted file with password:

```
gpg -c passwords.txt.gpg
```

how can I open it with vi, edit it, then close it? (So that no passwords.txt file will be created, the decrypted passwords.txt is only in the memory! - better: after closing the passwords.txt.gpg file, the memory should be cleaned, so it shouldn't contain unencrypted passwords).

Comment: You may be looking for a password manager such as `keepass`. It has command line functionality, and a GUI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Original Answer

The [gnupg plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=661) for Vim does this:

> This script implements transparent editing of gpg encrypted files. The
>   filename must have a ".gpg", ".pgp" or ".asc" suffix. When opening
>   such a file the content is decrypted, when opening a new file the
>   script will ask for the recipients of the encrypted file. The file
>   content will be encrypted to all recipients before it is written. The
>   script turns off viminfo and swapfile to increase security.

#### EDIT #1

As of 2016-07-02, the original gnupg plugin is now no longer being maintained:

> Due to the lack of time I'm not able to continue the development of this script. James McCoy took over development. New versions can be found at [vimscript #3645](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645).

There is however a new version:

- [gnupg.vim - Plugin for transparent editing of gpg encrypted files. : vim online](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3645)

Answer (score 1):

If you truly mean a gpg file, then the gnupg plugin as mentioned is your best option.

If you mean "how can I open, edit, and save an encrypted file with vim" then you might also explore the -x option.  It will allow you to enter a password and then save the file in an encrypted form, and does the right thing in terms of encrypting the .swp file as well.

See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#encryption

Be advised:

1. the cm=blowfish option is vital, otherwise you're saving with very
   weak crypto
2. I don't know if vim scrubs the memory before exit

Also, I don't know if keepass (mentioned above) as a command-line counterpart for Linux, but PasswordSafe (available for Windows and Linux) does: http://nsd.dyndns.org/pwsafe/
It allows you to edit entries in the shell, though if you want more freeform notes, full-screen editing, etc. you'd want something vi-friendly.

Comment: A handy warning from the vimdoc link: `"WARNING: If you make a typo when entering the key and then write the file and exit, the text will be lost!"`.