# Is there a way to edit a password-protected file without having to retype the password all the time?

Tags: vim, encryption, gpg

I want to encrypt a text file using a password and a way to safely edit that file.

The problem I am having is that I haven't managed to find a simple way to do that while only requiring the password for the decryption process.

---

As recommended in [this other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46506/how-to-edit-a-gpg-file-with-vi), I am currently trying to use gpg to encrypt my file and [vim-gnupg](https://github.com/jamessan/vim-gnupg) to edit it.

The first alternative I tried was to encrypt with `gpg --encrypt --default-recipient-self`. This works well with vim-gnupg and gpg-agent in terms of not having to type the passphrase all the time but I find the use of assymetric crypto a bit cumbersome. Why do I need to create a key pair with my name and email and use assymetric crypto if all I am doing is encrypt things for myself? I'd also need to carry the key files with me instead of just the encrypted file.

The second alternative I tried was to encrypt with `gpg --symmetric`, which only asks for a passphrase. This time the problem was with not having to type the password over and over. When vim-gnupg saves the file it asks for a new password (and has me type it twice) instead of just reusing the same password that was used to decrypt the file in the first place. Is there a way to not do that?

Comment: Btw, the reason I am using gpg here instead of vim's built-in encryption feature (or something similar) is that I will want to be able to access the encrypted file from other scripts, and gpg is going to be better for that.

Comment: Beware of [security issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469518/310237)

Answer (score 2):

The GPG man page has several options you're probably interested in, that you could work into your own personal *decrypt-edit-encrypt* script/function. Like:

- `--passphrase-fd n` - Read the passphrase from file descriptor n
- `--passphrase-file file` - Read  the passphrase from file *file*... Obviously, a passphrase stored in a file
            is of questionable security if other users can read  this  file.
            Don't use this option if you can avoid it.
- `--passphrase string` - Use  string as the passphrase... Obviously, this is of very  questionable
            security  on  a  multi-user system. Don't use this option if you
            can avoid it.

Placing a keyfile in ram (tmpfs) and not readable by anyone else might be adequate. Or for Linux you could look into the kernel's key management facility i.e. `keyctl`

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/1358025/942947) is an updated and more in-depth version of this answer (always by Xen2050).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to do what you want with the standard tools.

That said, a really simple wrapper script could accomplish this.

Alternatively, if youre on Linux, you can use [pyrite](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11308), which is a GUI wrapper for gpg & openssl. With it, you can type your password into the GUI a single time to decrypt, edit the decrypted text, and then press a button to re-encrypt (which uses the same passphrase).